# List elements as argument in decorator (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, arguments, decorator

I am trying to solve this task: Create a function generating an array of random numbers and use decorator to square each element in the array.
I do not know how can I have the array elements as the arguments in decorator.

```
import random


def square_them(function):
    def case(*args, **kwargs):
        numbers = function(*args, **kwargs)
        return numbers ** 2

    return case


@square_them
def array_creator():
    randomlist = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        numbers = random.randint(1, 100)
        randomlist.append(numbers)
    print(randomlist)


array_creator()
```

I am getting an error:

> line 7, in case
> return numbers ** 2
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'

Any idea please? Thank you.

Comment: Please see [ask] and the [help]. What exactly are you asking? Are you encountering an error? Unexpected output? If so, what is the error exactly? What is the unexpected output, and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Please, boil this down to a [mcve]. If you are getting an error, produce an example that demonstrates that error, and remove the irrelevant details. Almost certainly, the fact that you are using a decorator is totally irrelevant. Please understand, this is not a debugging service or a tutoring service.

Comment: As to "I do not know how can I have the array elements as the arguments in decorator." well, the *list* is successfully being passed as an argument to the wrapper function in the decorator. That isn't the problem. Again, **please come back with a [mcve]**

Comment: Note, your `array_creator` function **returns `None`**

Comment: #juanpa.arrivillaga many thanks for all your comments. I am trying my best, sorry. Im new here and beginner in Python. I see that the function returns None, but have no idea how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
import random

def square_them(function):
    def case(*args, **kwargs):
        numbers = function(*args, **kwargs)
        return [i ** 2 for i in numbers]
    return case


@square_them
def array_creator():
    randomlist = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        numbers = random.randint(1, 100)
        randomlist.append(numbers)
    return randomlist


print(array_creator())
```

Output:

```
[2809, 3364, 400, 8100, 3025, 4096, 4, 2601, 144]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
print([i*2 for i in random.sample(range(10), 5)])
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need to use @decorator